# What was this computer I remembered?

Tags: identify-this-computer, windows

When I went to primary school in 1995 I remember the school had a classroom full of old computers. It took the school 2 years but eventually they did replace them with more modern systems. The two things I remember of these old boxes was the pipe game and the moonlanding game.

The pipe game gave you 30 seconds to start laying pipes before the toxic waste began to flow and then you had to keep it flowing for as long as possible by laying tiles. The moonlanding game I remember as being hard, you had to use the arrow keys to keep it from crashing.

I do think these were windows systems; I would be really curious as to what systems these could have been.

Comment: Indicate which country please.

Comment: Please indicate the nation and describe the system physically.

Comment: If you need OP to add more information you should also flag the question or vote to close until the necessary information is added. That's an important part of the quality control on Stack Exchange.

Comment: On C64, there was a pipeline game, named super pipeline 2. Did it look so? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Kl2Y3tcGaE4

Comment: @MauryMarkowitz The name of the OP and the user distribution of the SO suggests USA. Probably a coast region.

Comment: The poster claims to live in South Africa. That doesn't mean they went to school there.

Comment: Could it be Risc OS: Lander https://youtu.be/qybfBWuLXfQ?t=11 and Pipe Mania? https://youtu.be/XXZ9w63pRSk?t=95

Answer (score 1):

If you went to school in the UK they were likely Research Machines PCs running Window Box, a custom shell on top of MS Windows. I remember versions for Windows 3.0 onwards. I used these in infant and junior classrooms in 1995-1996 and they were still popular in 1999 when I started teaching.
Schools liked them because they were easy to manage and you could set them to different levels of complexity depending on the age of the child and they included a lot of education software for primary. They also allowed a primitive multi user system for storing documents.

Comment: Apparently, this probably isn't even the right country! Though I also remember a Windows 95 RM system with this software in my primary school (perpetually on and unused, since it didn't connect to the one-user-per-class XP network).